# Planning backwards in MS Project

Tags: ms-project, dependencies

I need to plan some activities backwards from a fixed deadline. I used SF dependencies for that, but there's a slight problem. Let's say I have the following simple plan:

```
1 Milestone
2 Activity A    2 hours    1SF
3 Activity B    9 hours    1SF
4 Activity C    1 hour     2SF;3SF
```

I expect Activity C to start before BOTH Activity A and B (i.e., 9 hours before Milestone), but it starts before Activity A, only 2 hours before Milestone.

Is there a way to force MS Project to respect both constraints?

Comment: If you want to plan from a finish date, set the finish date in Project Information, select to schedule from the Finish Date and use F to S relationships.  It will automatically use ALAP constraints, pushing all tasks to the finish date.   Regarding "respecting both constraints" - I think you mean links.  Remove the link from Activity C to A.

Comment: That was my first thought Julie, but the OP only wants to back-load "some" of the tasks and therefore I rejected the "Schedule from Finish Date" option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use standard FS relations for predecessors, and set task constraint type 'As late as possible':

```
1 milestone - prerequisites: 2,3
2 Activity A - 4
3 Activity B - 4
4 Activity C
```

You should set 'as late as possible' constraint on tasks 2-4, and set task 1 to the required fixed date ('start no earlier than' constraint).